# Dealing with NSManagedObjects when using MVVM

Tags: cocoa, core-data, mvvm

I've been struggling with a good answer to this one for a while:

How do you deal with NSManagedObjects as the Model in MVVM?

I've tried a few different approaches:

- Retaining a copy of the `NSManagedObject` on the ViewModel — although this seems a bit dangerous to me, with the potential for threading issues
- Unpacking the `NSManagedObject` into the properties I actually use on the VM via an `-initWithModel:` method — this would mean I no longer receive any updates to the `NSManagedObject` after the initial initialisation
- Retaining a copy of the `NSManagedObject`'s `NSManagedObjectID`, and using an `NSManagedObjectContext` specifically for each ViewModel instance to retrieve and monitor a private `NSManagedObject` and it's attributes — this seems a bit heavy to do this for every ViewModel instance (and potentially quite fragile)

None of these seem ideal. I have an idea in my head that it might be best to combine passing in an initial `NSManagedObject` instance via `-initWithModel:`, but only retaining the `NSManagedObjectID`, then listening for core data save notifications and weeding out any that don't relate to the retained object ID.

Comment: Out of curiosity - how do you *MVVM* in Cocoa? IMHO the Cocoa frameworks aren't exactly designed for that kind of loose coupling between views, view models and models

Comment: NSView/NSViewController I treat as the "View" later, VM is just a custom NSObject subclass and Model tends to be NSManagedObjects. It keeps a lot of code out of my NSView/NSViewController, which is nice.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, and I don't know if this is necessarily the best practice, is pass in the model and then bind properties of the view model to (possibly mapped) properties on the model. That way you get updates through the view model. It does leave a little bit open to threading problems, but you can use `deliverOn:` to ensure that updates are always delivered on the main scheduler.

Comment: I keep coming back to this method, as there's no other (simple) way to get at changes to the model's attributes. I've recently started vending a shared serial dispatch queue and a RACScheduler based on that queue that I use across all of my classes to retrieve, modify and create my managed objects — that seems to be working well, but it's still a lot of mental gymnastics. Thanks, Ash!

Comment: Ash: I'm would like to get along with MVVM and Core Data. Would be pleased if you can update your answer with some code for better understanding of your point. Thanks in advance.